# HTTP Loopback Connections are not enabled on this server - wordpress on docker

Tags: wordpress, docker, kitematic

I have a wordpress official container with a dock port 80 mapped to 32795 external... when I go to administration area of wordpress I get this error:

Important: HTTP Loopback Connections are not enabled on this server. If you need to contact your web host, tell them that when PHP tries to connect back to the site at the URL `http://localhost:32795/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php` and it gets the error `cURL error 7: Failed to connect to localhost port 32795: Connection refused`. There may be a problem with the server configuration (eg local DNS problems, mod_security, etc) preventing connections from working properly.

I think the problem is that the site inside the container tries to communicate with the 32795 port instead of 80, but it can not because this door is only seen from the outside of the container...

I created a script inside the site with phpinfo, and I checked the loopback connections are on...

There is a solution for this? I have docker un windows with kitematic

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had a similar problem running WordPress with Nginx on Docker Desktop for Windows. I needed to add an entry to the container's `hosts` file that directed my `local.example.com` domain to hit my ingress-nginx controller so that WordPress' loopback requests would work. Although my setup might be slightly different this might help you.

Open `/Windows/System32/drivers/etc/hosts` and copy the IP address that's next to `host.docker.internal`. Add an entry to the container's `hosts` file on startup that ties the domain to the hosts IP by doing one of the following. `IP` is what you copied from your machine's hosts file by `host.docker.internal`

Docker argument:

```
--add-host="local.example.com:IP"
```

Docker compose:

```
extra_hosts:
  - "local.example.com:IP"
```

Kubernetes:

```
hostAliases:
- ip: "IP"
  hostnames:
  - "local.example.com"
```

Answer (score 2):

Problem is inside the container the opened port is `80` and docker is exposing `32795` for external connections

Wordpress configuration is pointing to port `32795`, you might expose port `80` by doing `docker run -p 80:80` and change wordpress configuration to use port `80`

If you can't use port `:80` a little bit more complicated solution is to use `iptables` port forwarding internally

Example

```
➜  ~  docker run -d --cap-add=NET_ADMIN --cap-add=NET_RAW -p 5000:80 nginx                
835b039cc92bd9f32b960181bf370d39869c88f5a757423966b467fe01ac219e                          
➜  ~  docker exec -it 835b039cc92bd9 bash                                                 
root@835b039cc92b:/# apt update -qqq ; apt install iptables -yqqq 
root@835b039cc92b:/# iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -o lo -p tcp --dport 5000 -j REDIRECT --to-
port 80
root@835b039cc92b:/# apt install telnet -yqqq
root@835b039cc92b:/# telnet localhost 5000
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
^]
telnet> quit
Connection closed.
root@835b039cc92b:/# exit

# from outside the container
➜  ~  telnet localhost 5000                                               
Trying ::1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
^]
telnet> quit
Connection closed.
```

Answer (score 0):

I encountered something similar on MacOS trying to install a Bitnami WP/MariaDB deployment using [their docker-compose.yml](https://github.com/bitnami/containers/tree/main/bitnami/wordpress#how-to-use-this-image). I installed a theme using AJAX and while installing, it gave me the same warning. To resolve this with docker-compose you should edit your service and add

```
extra_hosts:
  - "localhost:172.17.0.1"
```

I think it's because it's the gateway's static IP of docker's `bridge` network.